# NHibernate's equivalent of LINQ to SQL's and EF's Translate<T>()

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sqldatareader, datareader

I have a query that due to performance reasons I need to craft the actual command using raw ADO.NET (it involves table-valued parameters). With LINQ to SQL or EF, I could simply pass the `DbDataReader` that was returned by `DbCommand.ExecuteReader()` to the `DataContext.Translate<T>(DbDataReader)` or `ObjectContext.Translate<T>(DbDataReader)` method and it would convert the result-set to objects, returning an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Is there any equivalent API in NHibernate that I can either pass a `DbDataReader`/`IDataReader` or even an `DbCommand`/`IDbCommand` and get NHibernate entities back?

Or perhaps there's a way to intercept the construction of the command created by `ISession.CreateQuery(string)` so that I could modify the underlying `DbCommand` to work the way I need to?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use `CreateSQLQuery`?

Comment: @penfold: Yes, because, as I've mentioned, I need to use table-valued parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably create a custom UserType to handle the table-valued parameter.

NHibernate does not expose the DataReader -> entities transformation in any public methods.

Comment: It seems that this is a good place to start. `IUserType.NullSafeSet()` has a parameter of type `IDbCommand` which is what I need to add the table-value parameter.

Comment: It was indeed the easiest way to make that work, thanks! I got to the point where I could do the following: `session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id IN (SELECT Value FROM :tableType)")`. But that requires calling `IQuery.AddEntity()` and such. I tried to move one abstraction level up by using HQL with the following: `session.CreateQuery("FROM Customers WHERE Id IN (SELECT Value FROM :tableType)")`, but that throws a `Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException`. I want to get to the point where I can use this from LINQ, but isn't HQL the next logical step? Maybe I need to skip HQL?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to move higher than SQL without deeper hacking. Just keep the SQL.